# Get German title and year of movie with regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove everything from string except title and year of a movie

I would like to keep everything that's not in a bracket:

```
**Dirty.Work.Wie.deweit.wuerdest.Du.gehen.2018**[.German.AC3.WEBRip]
**Zwei.baerenstarke.Typen.1983**[.DE.EN.DTSHD.MasteDEr.5.1.2160p.HDR10.x265-kellerratte]
**The.Hills.Have.Eyes.1977**[.COMPLETE.UHD.BLURAY-UNTOUCHED]
**Wonder.Woman.1984.2020.**[GERMAN.DUBBED.DL.2160p.HDR.WEB.x265]
**Wonder.Woman.1984**[.GERMAN.]**2020**[.DUBBED.DL.2160p.HDR.WEB.x265]
**2012**[.German.]**2006**[.DL.2160p.UHD.BluRay.HDR.HEVC.Remux]

**Sherlock.Holmes.2009**[.German.DL.]**2022**[.ock.Holmes.UHD.BluRay.2160p.UHD.BluRay.HDR.HEVC.Remux]
```

Expected:

```
Dirty.Work.Wie.deweit.wuerdest.Du.gehen.2018
Zwei.baerenstarke.Typen.1983
The.Hills.Have.Eyes.1977
Wonder.Woman.1984 2020 
Wonder.Woman.1984 2020 
2012 2006 
Sherlock.Holmes.2009 2022
```

This is what I tried:

```
((?<=\b\d{4}\b)|\b(German|DE)\b.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Z4cRMn/1

Does anyone has a clue how to do it? Need some examples maybe

Comment: This is a bad approach.  You are putting a bias on the question.  So you likely will only get regex answers.   There be better solutions than using regex.   I can usually use strpos and create a much more efficient solution than regex.  But it's okay, if you only want a regex solution.

Comment: The way you are presenting the problem is a bit misleading - you make it sound is if you wanted to remove anything inside `[...]`, but that is not actually the case, and only your example on an external platform makes that clear.

Comment: I doubt you can get *exact* output like you showed. Try https://regex101.com/r/YtBAUe/1. I think it is the closest solution you can get provided your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close to what you need using

```
\[[^\]\[]*]|\W*\b(?:\d{4}|German|DE)\b(?!.*\[[^\]\[]*]).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YtBAUe/1). *Details*:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^\]\[]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `|` - or
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\d{4}|German|DE)` - four digits or `German` or `DE`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!.*\[[^\]\[]*])` - immediately to the right of the current location, there should not be

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `\[[^\]\[]*]` - `[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.